# python regex with repeating subpattern

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am wondering if there is a 'smart' way (one regex expression) to extract IDs from the following paragraph:

`...

imgList = '9/optimized/1260089_fpx.tif,0/optimized/1260090_fpx.tif';

...`

The result shoul be a list containing `1260089` and `1260090`. The count of the IDs might be up to 10.

I need something like:

```
re.findall('imgList = (some expression)', string)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Best would be to use a single regex finding all the numbers. I call for [re.findall](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
>>> imgList = '9/optimized/1260089_fpx.tif,0/optimized/1260090_fpx.tif'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('optimized/([0-9]*)_fpx', imgList)
['1260089', '1260090']
```

You could of course make the regex stronger, but if the data is as you indicated, this should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = '9/optimized/1260089_fpx.tif,0/optimized/1260090_fpx.tif'

print(re.findall(r'(\d+)_fpx.tif', s))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `optimzed/` an `_fpx` part is not ensured and the ID is between 7 and 10 digits 
you could do something like

```py
import re
re.findall('[\d]{7,10}', imgList)
```

This will find a 7 to 10 digit number in the string, hence, IDs with 0-6 or more than 10 digits will be excluded.

Comment: This approach is not what I was looking for, but might get the job done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
imgList = '9/optimized/1260089_fpx.tif,0/optimized/1260090_fpx.tif'
re.findall(r'([0-9]){7}',imgList)

['1260089', '1260090']
```

The code can only meet your situation.